# How to fix Access Denied on a S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I try to access my bucket root (https://mybucket-public.s3.amazonaws.com) I've got an **Access Denied**, however, If I access directly the "**index.html**" I can properly see the page.

[image]

**Bucket policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-public/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with a workaround:

In the Cloudfront distribution Settings, I had the following:

**Default Root Object**: index.html

Now when accessing the abcdef123.cloudfront.net it points to the bucket's index.html.